# Is it possible to have recursive function with constant space?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I'm trying to solve this problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/sort-list/ and the constraints are Time = O(nlog(n)) and Space = O(1).

```
Sort a linked list in O(n log n) time using constant space complexity.

Example 1:

Input: 4->2->1->3
Output: 1->2->3->4
Example 2:

Input: -1->5->3->4->0
Output: -1->0->3->4->5
```

For the time complexity, it can be done but for the constant space, I've been struggling and a lot of people posted solutions using merge sort with recursive function which I'm not convinced it only takes O(1) space.

What am I missing here? Is it possible to implement recursive function for singly linked list with O(1) space?

Comment: Your last sentence seems contradictory. Did you mean O(1) *space*?

Comment: Oh sorry. My bad. Let me fix it.

Comment: Putting half of a question as link is not really good. The site may go down or the contents may change, invalidating your question.

Comment: In this case the linked question does not contain anything that is not already here.

Comment: @tar Actually there is an important detail missing.  Which is that you are sorting a linked list, not sorting an array.  Which means that the heap sort solution that both of us came up with doesn't actually work.  (Because heapify assumes an array data structure.)

Comment: You can do an iterative (non-recursive) merge sort in O(1) extra space. No reason that can't be done with a linked list. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-merge-sort-for-linked-list/

Comment: "I've been struggling and a lot of people posted solutions using merge sort with recursive function" --> Why the _recursive_ requirement?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The requirement is to clarify whether claimed `O(1)` solutions that leetcode accepts as `O(1)` actually are `O(1)`.  The answer is that they aren't.  (They generally have `O(log(n))` call frames which takes `O(log(n))` memory.)

Comment: @btilly So without the unnecessary recursion requirement (code can loop), there is O(1) call frames which takes O(1) memory.

Comment: If you implement the iterative solution as a tail-recursive function, then it can be O(1) space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing nothing.  The recursive merge sort takes `O(log(n))` space.  That said, leetcode's check for space efficiency is unable to tell the difference between `O(1)` and `O(log(n))` - all they do is put a memory bound on it, run it, and see that it hasn't blown up.

If the data was in an array, multiple efficient solutions exist that take `O(1)` extra space.  The simplest being a heapsort.

However with a singly linked list, I'm dubious that there is an answer that is actually `O(1)` space.

**UPDATE**

My being dubious notwithstanding, it is possible.  See Jim Mischel's comment.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is O(n log n) with O(1) extra space. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-merge-sort-for-linked-list/. The non-recursive merge sort of an array is O(1) extra space. I don't see any reason you can't do that with a linked list.

Comment: @JimMischel Oh, clever!  Yes, that one is `O(1)` space.

Comment: Its memory O(1) with a LL.

Comment: Thank you btilly for your answer and thank you Jim Mischel for your link. Would you mind posting an answer here? I'll check the solution and mark your answer as correct.